# Estimate the chance n rolls of m fair six-sided dice

Tags: r, dice

Similar with [De mere problem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/deMeresProblem.html)

I want to generate a Monte Carlo simulation to estimate the probability of rolling at least one [image: 1] from `n` rolls of `m` fair six-sided dice.

My code:

```
m<-5000
n<-3
x<-replicate(m, sample(1:6,n,TRUE)==1)
p<-sum(x)/m
```

p is the probability estimated. Here I get the value 0.4822.

My questions:

1) Is there any other way without using `sum` to do it?

2) I doubt the code is wrong as the probability maybe too high.

Comment: The flag link should be next to the edit link below the post.

Comment: It's not apparent that this would be on-topic on [SO], so I am reluctant to migrate it.  The main problem is that it lacks a definite question.

Comment: @whuber, I just updated the question.

Comment: Thank you.  I'm still reluctant to migrate because you haven't indicated what "probability" you're trying to calculate.  Until you do that, it's not at all clear what the code is intended to do. It's difficult even to reverse-engineer your code, because it produces numbers that obviously are not probabilities.  (Set `n<-10`, say, and re-run it.)

Comment: Thank you @whuber. I edited it again.

Comment: Neither of your two questions seems good. (1) Why do you want to do it without `sum`? What's wrong with using `sum`? You could use `mean()` instead, but it's the same thing really. (2) Isn't a question, but your code looks right for what you describe. But you may want to work on your question statement. Maybe you mean *"I want to use `m` Monte Carlo samples to determine the probability of getting at least one `1` when rolling `n` dice?"*

Comment: @Dave2e That's not correct.  The chance is 1 - (5/6)^3, which is around 0.42.  As the OP notes, this is related to the [Chevalier de Mere's problem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/deMeresProblem.html), analyzed (correctly) by Blaise Pascal in the mid-17th century.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although the question as stated is a little unclear, the code suggests you want to estimate the chance of obtaining at least one outcome of "1" among `n` independent dice and that you aim to estimate this by simulating the experiment `m` times.

**Program simulations from the inside out.**  Begin with a single iteration.  You started well, but to be perfectly clear let's redo it using a highly suggestive syntax.  Try this:

```
1 %in% sample(1:6,n,TRUE)
```

This uses `sample` to realize the results of `n` independent fair dice and checks whether the outcome `1` appears among any of them.

Once you are satisfied that this emulates your experiment (run it a bunch of times), then indeed `replicate` will perform the simulation:

```
x <- replicate(m, 1 %in% sample(1:6,n,TRUE))
```

That produces `m` results.  Each will be TRUE (interpreted as equal to 1) in all iterations where `1` appeared and otherwise will be FALSE (interpreted as 0).  Consequently, the average number of times `1` appeared can be obtained as

```
mean(x)
```

This *empirical frequency* is a good estimate of the *theoretical probability*.

---

As a check, note that `1` will *not* appear on a single die with a probability of 1-1/6 = 5/6 and therefore--because the `n` dice are independent--will *not* appear on any of them with a probability of (5/6)^n.  Consequently the chance a `1` *will* appear must be 1 - (5/6)^n.  Let us output those two values: the simulation mean and theoretical result.  We might also include a *Z score*, which is a measure of how far away from the theoretical result the mean is.  Typically, Z scores between -2 and 2 aren't significant evidence of any discrepancy.

Here's the full code.  Although there are faster ways to write it, this is very fast already and is about as clear as one could make it.

```
m <- 5000     # Number of simulation iterations
n <- 3        # Number of dice per iteration 
set.seed(17)  # For reproducible results
x <- replicate(m, 1 %in% sample(1:6,n,TRUE))

# Compare to a theoretical result.
theory <- 1-(5/6)^n
avg <- mean(x)
Z <- (avg - theory) / sd(x) * sqrt(length(x))
c(Mean=signif(avg, 5), Theoretical=signif(theory, 5), Z.score=signif(Z, 3))
```

The output is

> Mean Theoretical     Z.score
>
> 0.4132    0.4213   -1.1600

Notice that neither result is anywhere near `n/6`, which would be 1/2 = 0.500.

Comment: What is meant by `%in%`? I am new to R.

Comment: In general, you can learn about unfamiliar parts of base `R` by asking for help from the command line.  Although the help is not always satisfactory, this really is the first thing you should do before seeking further.  In this case the manual page is available via `?"%in%"`.  As you might guess, `%in%` tests whether each component of its left hand side appears within the vector on the right hand side.  For instance, `3:4 %in% 1:3` returns `TRUE FALSE` because `3` is in the vector `1:3` but `4` is not.